# subtract two dates

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to list students which added in the table in specific number of days.

```
@NumberOfDays INT = 15 -- When I list them the added subtraction result must match this result

SELECT S.Name, S.Surname, S.DateAdded
FROM STUDENT S
WHERE (SELECT CAST(GETDATE()-S.DateAdded) = @NumberOfDays)
```

but this just doesnt work. can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DATEADD` with a negative *increment* will deduct so;

```
where S.DateAdded >= dateadd(day, -@NumberOfDays, getdate())
```

For anything added in the last 15 days.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the function DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL), the following should work:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfDays INT = 15 -- When I list them the added subtraction result must match this result

SELECT S.Name, S.Surname, S.DateAdded
FROM STUDENT S
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, S.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = @NumberOfDays
```

For more information about this function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function in this way:

```
declare @numberofdays int
set @numberofdays = 15

SELECT S.Name, S.Surname, S.DateAdded
FROM STUDENT S
WHERE S.DateAdded >= dateadd(day, -@NumberOfDays, getdate())
```

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d8ca/1) with it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

You can use [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function in sql to get the date difference in days.

```
DECLARE @numberofdays as int
set @numberofdays = 15

SELECT S.Name, S.Surname, S.DateAdded
from STUDENT S
where datediff(dd,S.DateAdded,getdate())= @numberofdays;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.Name, S.Surname, S.DateAdded 
FROM STUDENT S 
WHERE (SELECT months_between(GETDATE(), S.DateAdded) = @NumberOfDays)
```

Comment: months between ? This is no good. No months between in mssql and we are talking days here